# Deeplinking in android with pathAdvancedPattern using regex

Tags: android, regex, deep-linking

I have some URLs to be opened by the app. They usually start with "a" or "ba" or "bb" or "bc", "be" and so on till "bz", except "bd".

```
I have used below to code in manifest: 

<data android:host="@string/deeplink_host"
      android:pathAdvancedPattern="/[a|ba-bc|be-bz].*"
      android:scheme="https"
/>
```

It is accepting URLs which start with "a", but it is not working in case of "ba", "bb", etc (on checking 2 chars (or substring)). I even tried using below codes, but none of them worked.

```
Code-1:    android:pathAdvancedPattern="/[a|e-f|ba-bc|be-bz].*"
Code-2:    android:pathAdvancedPattern="/[a|e-f|b(a-c)|b(e-z)].*"
Code-3:    android:pathAdvancedPattern="/[a|e-f|b[a-c]|b[e-z]].*"
```

Tried several other ways, but none of them worked. Please give a solution which accepts allowing substring in "ranges"

Comment: Should you also match URLs starting with `e` or `f` and that's all? I see you added them into your pattern but didn't talk about them in the question.

Comment: Yes, i require those too. Altogether, i want the regex to support URL paths starting with “a” or “e” or “f” “ba” “bb” “bc” “be”…..”bz” (except bd)

Answer (score 0):

#### If you had a real regex

With a full regex engine like PCRE, it would be something like this:

```
^\/(a|b[a-ce-z]|[e-f]).*
```

See it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/ftXk0b/1

#### But, no, you can't do it with *pathAdvancedPattern*

As I understand, **you can't use the `( | )` syntax with
*pathAdvancedPattern***, even with the
[*PATTERN_ADVANCED_GLOB*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PatternMatcher#PATTERN_ADVANCED_GLOB) option. This
[article about handling complex paths](https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-handle-deep-link-with-complex-path-like-this-811216a0c802)
explains it quite well.

So the problem is that rewriting it to `/[a-f][a-ce-z].*` would not
be the solution, either. Effectively, a path such as `/address` would
not match because of the `d` in the second position.

I'm not 100% sure, but you could probably split it into several
`<data>` tags, like this:

```xml
<data android:host="@string/deeplink_host"
      android:pathAdvancedPattern="/[ac-f].*"
      android:scheme="https"
/>
<data android:host="@string/deeplink_host"
      android:pathAdvancedPattern="/b[ace-z].*"
      android:scheme="https"
/>
```

This way, the first `<data>` tag would:

- match `/a.*`.
- not match `/b.*` (done later in the second `<data>` tag).
- match `/c.*`, `/d.*`, `/e.*` and `/f.*`.

and the second `<data>` tag would:

- match `/ba.*`, `/bb.*` or `/bc.*`.
- not match `/bd.*`, as desired.
- match `/be.*`, `/bf.*`, ... until `/bz.*`.

And here's another article that could help, which explains
[how to manage a complex DeepLinks scheme in your Android App](https://medium.com/android-news/how-to-manage-a-complex-deeplinks-scheme-on-your-android-app-d441143cec7e).

#### Answer to your comment about URLs with `/services`

You added in your comment that you would like to match
`/services/login.php` and `/servicesData` but not any other
URL starting with `/services/...`. You had a try by using a
pattern like `/services[^/].*` which would match URLs like
`/servicesData`, `/services-flow`, `/servicestate`, etc.

As you can't use proper regular expressions but have to stick
with advanced GLOB patterns, you'll have to use two patterns,
just like I proposed in my answer above:

```xml
<data android:host="@string/deeplink_host"
      android:pathAdvancedPattern="/services/login\\.php"
      android:scheme="https"
/>
<data android:host="@string/deeplink_host"
      android:pathAdvancedPattern="/servicesData"
      android:scheme="https"
/>
```

To match the dot in "login.php", you'll have to add two
backslashes in front of it. The first one is because `.` in a pattern
is normally used to match any char, so adding a backslash before
is to escape it and say "match the dot character".
The second backslash is because I see in
[this article](https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-handle-deep-link-with-complex-path-like-this-811216a0c802#b9da)
that XML itself uses backslash to escape some characters.

If you need to match `/servicesData` and also `/servicesData/`,
then you could probably try to modify it this way:

```xml
<data android:host="@string/deeplink_host"
      android:pathAdvancedPattern="/servicesData/{0,1}"
      android:scheme="https"
/>
```

`{0,1}` means that what is proceeding, here it's the "/" char, can be
repeated 0 to 1 times. I let you have a try with it as I can't test it on my side.

Comment: Thanks for the bottom solution. It is almost working, but I'm again stuck in excluding forward slashes. Eg: My URLs are "/services/login.php" & "/servicesData"
I want to exclude URL which has "services/". I tried using android:pathAdvancedPattern="/services\[^\/\].*" as well as "/services[^/].*", but none of them worked.

Comment: I'm sorry @NikhilReddy, but I am not an Android developer and never had a go with it. Effectively, using `[^/]` should normally match any char not being a slash. But if you only want to match `/services/login.php` and `/servicesData` then just don't add the `.*` behind your pattern and put them in two different `<data>` elements.